# macOS High Sierra - set default Wi-Fi

Tags: macos, network

I wish to set a Wi-Fi access point as default to connect to. I was told to go to Network Preferences and click on **Advanced...** button to set the default. I am unable to find it. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under **Preferred Networks**, drag and drop the listed access points in the order of priority you want your Mac to connect to them. Drag the most preferred one to **top**. Your Mac will connect to it when it is available instead of connecting to other available Wi-Fi networks further down the list.

Comment: In addition, it is a wise idea to remove any Wi-Fi networks in this list you no longer use.

Comment: I see..this is why I can't let go of Mac. So simple!